# DXF to SVG using Inkscape CLI on Mac OS

Tags: svg, inkscape, dxf

I'm trying to convert DXF files (from Fusion360) to plain SVG files using the Inkscape CLI. It works fine with one small annoyance: the Inkscape GUI promps me on how to read the dxf file (the settings in there are fine, all I do is click ok).
It's the same dialog you get when importing a dxf file through the Gui.

The command I'm running:

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape -z -l <absolutePath>/output.svg <absolutePath>/input.dxf
```

I've also tried this with no success with regard to the dialog popup:

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape -z -f <absolutePath>/input.dxf -l <absolutePath>/output.svg
```

-z means no GUI. Which works in terms of no Inkscape instance starting (XQuartz is starting though), but the pesky dialog can just assume ok and move on rather than checking with me for an ok click.

To be clear, the actual export is just fine. It's only the Gui dialog that's crashing my CLI-high :)

In short: any chance on flagging that dialog to go ahead without actual interaction from my part?

Specs:
MacOS 10.13.
Inkscape 0.91

Comment: There is a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1266193